# Get all string properties of an object and any descendent objects

Tags: c#, reflection

Given any complex object, for example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use *reflection* to obtain all the `string`s for instance of `Person` and any child objects, in this case `Address`, and theoretically any potential objects in `Address` etc. In this example this would retrieve `PropertyInfo` for `Person.Name`, `Address.Street`, and `Address.City`

Comment: What is your definition of a "child object"? Any reference type?

Comment: What have you tried?  When you use reflection to examine the properties of an object, what do you find?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Its fairly clear that the OP wants to do a deep scan for any property of type string on an object and its children. From the example above they want to see Name, Street and City. I'm sure this must have been answered before but a quick google search turns up nothing and its a sensible question. I think it deserves an answer (or a link to an existing answer if there is one)

Answer (score 3):

You can scan the property *graph* (let it be *Breadth First Search* - BFS) in order to obtain all public properties:

```
private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> PublicProps(Type value) {
  HashSet<PropertyInfo> emitted = new HashSet<PropertyInfo>();

  BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;

  List<PropertyInfo> agenda = value
    .GetProperties(flags)
    .ToList();

  while (agenda.Any()) {
    for (int i = agenda.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      PropertyInfo item = agenda[i];

      agenda.RemoveAt(i);

      if (!emitted.Add(item))
        continue;

      yield return item;

      agenda.AddRange(item.PropertyType.GetProperties(flags));
    }
  }
}
```

And then use *Linq* to filter out `string` properties:

```
var result = PublicProps(typeof(Person))
  .Where(prop => prop.CanRead) // to be on the safe side if you want to read
  .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
```

Outcome:

```
System.String Name
System.String City
System.String Street
```

Please, notice that *recursion* is not a solution in *general case*, for instance for

```
public class Person {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
  public string Street { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public Person HouseOwner { get; set; } // <- circular property
}
```

Comment: For another example where naïve recursion could go too deep (infinitely deep): `public class Person {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Person Mother { get; set; }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to scan for properties.

```
    public static void FindStringMembers(Type t, List<string>PropertyNames, int stackDepth = 0) 
    {
        if (stackDepth >= 10) {
            return;
        }

        var f = t.GetProperties();

        var stringProperties = f.Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string)).Select(x => x.Name);

        PropertyNames.AddRange(stringProperties);

        var otherProperties = f.Where(x => x.PropertyType != typeof(string));

        foreach (var property in otherProperties) {
            FindStringMembers(property.PropertyType, PropertyNames, stackDepth + 1);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bob = new Person();

        var deepScan = new List<string>();

        FindStringMembers(bob.GetType(), deepScan);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", deepScan));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getPRopNames(typeof(Person));

        }

        public static void getPRopNames(Type fromObject)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo oneProp in fromObject.GetProperties())
            {
                if (oneProp.PropertyType.IsValueType || oneProp.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(oneProp.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    getPRopNames(oneProp.PropertyType);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```